# depository/repository of Mathematica notebooks

Tags: files-and-directories

Is there a depository/repository of Mathematica notebooks (not necessarily Mathematica packages) where one can upload some of their notebooks so as others can access them easily?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com, http://library.wolfram.com,...

Comment: Michael's suggestion of the demonstration project is a good one, but it is only for particular types of notebooks focused on a single `Manipulate` command. I don't know of a general repository, but [searching github](https://github.com/search?l=Mathematica&q=Mathematica&type=Repositories) yields some interesting results

Comment: Thank you Michael and Simon for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Online collaboration using a notebook interface is one of the many use-cases that the Wolfram Cloud was specifically built to address.  See https://mathematica.wolframcloud.com/app/, and click around to explore.  I'm not sure what level, if any, of subscription is needed in order to share saved notebooks, or whether you are able to make such notebooks public versus granting permissions to a pre-defined set of collaborators, but by poking around, I'm sure one could find these answers.  Good luck!